# ¿Cómo seleccionar todos los datos de un tabla en java?

Tags: primefaces, java-ee, xhtml

Buenos dias,

Necesito seleccionar todos los datos de una tabla ( tiene paginado ).

Codigo:

```
  <p:dataTable  id="datos"
              var="f" 
              rowKey="#{f.num}"
              resizableColumns="true" 
              value="#{busquedaBean1.fuente}"
              selection="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}"
              style="margin-bottom:0;margin-top: 0%;"  
              paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} 
             {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}
             {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" >

    <!-- CONTENIDO DE LA TABLA -->
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" global="true"  listener="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}"   />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" global="true"  listener="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}"   />

    <p:column headerText="Nombre" style="width:80%;" sortBy="#{f.nombre}">
        <h:outputText value="#{f.nombre}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Fecha" style="width:108%;" sortBy="#{f.fecha}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{f.fecha}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Bloqueo" width="65" sortBy="#{f.bloqueo}">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{f.bloqueo}" rendered="#{empty f.fechaBloqueo}" style="padding: 0 20%;"/>                                       
        <p:commandButton value="#{f.bloqueo}" rendered="#{ not empty f.fechaBloqueo}" id="detBloqueo" update=":form:carDetail" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Mostrar detalles" style="background: transparent;  color:#4297d7;border: 0px;" styleClass="detalles">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{f}" target="#{busquedaBean1.autor}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>


    <p:column width="16" >
        <h:commandLink title="Descargar" target="_blank"  actionListener="#{descargarFormaBean.descargar(f.forma,f.nombre)}">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" style="text-align:center;"></span>
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Directorio" width="190" sortBy="#{f.directorio}">
        <p:commandButton value="#{f.dir}"  id="detDirectorio" update=":form:dirDetail" oncomplete="PF('dirDialog').show()" title="Mostrar detalles" style="background: transparent;  color:black;border: 0px;" styleClass="detalles">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{f}" target="#{busquedaBean1.autor}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>

    <p:column  id="SelectFuentes"   style="width:16%;text-align:center" selectionMode="multiple" exportable="false"   >

    </p:column>



</p:dataTable>
```

Al momento de Seleccionar el CheckBox de la columna para seleccionar todos los datos, no me selecciona las otras paginas, solo me selecciona la pagina que esta activa ( la que el usuario esta viendo), y necesito que me seleccione todo.

> NOTA: Estuve investigando y dice que es un error en la version de primefaces 5.1 pero no estoy seguro.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Todos los datos de tu `datatable` están en la lista `#{busquedaBean1.fuente}`, si los quieres seleccionar todos, esa lista deberías usar

Comment: tengo una columna checkbox

Comment: Podrías usar el evento `event="toggleSelect"` `onToggleSelect(ToggleSelectEvent event)` para que cuando esté en la posición de seleccionar todo, tomes todos los datos del listado del `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya encontre la solucion:

Codigo:

```
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" global="true" update="@form"  listener="#{busquedaBean1.seleccionarTodos}"   />
```

Hay que crear ese metodo de ajax, luego nos vamos nuentro Bean.java( en mi caso es `busquedaBean1` y llamamos al metodo java:

Codigo:

```
/**
 * @return the isSelectedAll
 */
public boolean isIsSelectedAll() {
    return isSelectedAll;
}

/**
 * @param isSelectedAll the isSelectedAll to set
 */
public void setIsSelectedAll(boolean isSelectedAll) {
    this.isSelectedAll = isSelectedAll;
}



  public void seleccionarTodos(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
    if(isIsSelectedAll()==false){
        this.selectedFuentes=fuente;
        setIsSelectedAll(true);
    }else{
        this.selectedFuentes.clear();
        setIsSelectedAll(false);
    }
}


Y listo problema resuelto, espero que les sirva a todo.
```

Comment: Versiones anteriores de PrimeFaces 5.6 segun lo que eh probado, no seleccionan todos los datos del paginado ese codigo les servira de mucho :3